# What is the difference between specifying 'ON' at a join and after all the joins?

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I came across a code which joins two tables and on specifies the link (the 'ON' clause) between the three tables at the end.

The code was written like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tb1 AS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 AS b  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 AS c 
ON b.ColA = c.ColA ON a.ColA = b.ColA
```

The result of this was different from when I changed it to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tb1 AS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 AS b ON a.ColA = b.ColA
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 AS c ON b.ColA = c.ColA
```

Could someone please explain the difference between these two joins?

Comment: can you post both of your result, or the difference of result.

Comment: @DarkRob I saw this script yesterday and I honestly can't exactly remember which stored proc I was looking at. I really just need an explanation as to what the difference in the two scripts is.

Comment: It seems like a syntax quirk has fallen through the cracks.

Comment: Are you certain that both of the joins were `LEFT OUTER JOIN`-s? Because what you describe would make sense if the second join were actually an `INNER JOIN` or a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @OngaLeo-YodaVellem . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  It turns out your question is about standard SQL, so the database doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that the two queries yield different results, as they look logically equivalent to me. As another answer has pointed out, this is logically equivalent to the following query (but without duplicate column errors):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    tb1 AS a  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  *
            FROM    tbl2 AS b  
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 AS c 
                        ON b.ColA = c.ColA
        ) AS b
            ON a.ColA = b.ColA
```

i.e. it changes the order of operations, `tbl2` is joined to `tbl3`, first, then the result of that query is joined with `tb1`. This is typically more usefull when you need to `INNER JOIN` on a table that is already part of an `OUTER JOIN`. For example, if you only wanted to return records from `tbl2` where the corresponding entry was in `tbl3`, you couldn't change the original query to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb1 AS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 AS b ON a.ColA = b.ColA
INNER JOIN tbl3 AS c ON b.ColA = c.ColA
```

As this would also remove any records from `tb1` with no corresponding entry in `tbl2`, whereas if you wrote it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb1 AS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 AS b  
INNER JOIN tbl3 AS c 
ON b.ColA = c.ColA ON a.ColA = b.ColA
```

This is where the difference is more noticable. The latter is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    tb1 AS a  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  *
            FROM    tbl2 AS b  
                    INNER JOIN tbl3 AS c 
                        ON b.ColA = c.ColA
        ) AS b
            ON a.ColA = b.ColA
```

Which would correctly remove any records from `tbl2` where there was no corresponding record in `tbl3`, but retain records from `tbl1` that have no corresponding record in the resulting dataset of `tbl2` and `tbl3`.

**SAMPLE SCHEMA AND QUERIES**

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ColA INT);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ColA INT);
DECLARE @T3 TABLE (ColA INT);
INSERT @T1 (ColA) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT @T2 (ColA) VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT @T3 (ColA) VALUES (1);


-- query 1
SELECT *
FROM @T1 AS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN @T2 AS b ON a.ColA = b.ColA
LEFT OUTER JOIN @T3 AS c ON b.ColA = c.ColA;

-- query 2
SELECT * 
FROM @T1 AS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN @T2 AS b  
LEFT OUTER JOIN @T3 AS c 
ON b.ColA = c.ColA ON a.ColA = b.ColA;

-- query 3
SELECT *
FROM @T1 AS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN @T2 AS b ON a.ColA = b.ColA
INNER JOIN @T3 AS c ON b.ColA = c.ColA;

-- query 4
SELECT * 
FROM @T1 AS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN @T2 AS b  
INNER JOIN @T3 AS c 
ON b.ColA = c.ColA ON a.ColA = b.ColA
```

**RESULTS**

```
-- QUERY 1 & 2
T1.ColA     T2.ColA     T3.ColA
----------------------------------
1           1           1
2           2           NULL
3           NULL        NULL

-- QUERY 3
T1.ColA     T2.ColA     T3.ColA
----------------------------------
1           1           1

-- QUERY 4
T1.ColA     T2.ColA     T3.ColA
----------------------------------
1           1           1
2           NULL        NULL
3           NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is evaluated like the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb1 AS a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM tbl2 AS b  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 AS c 
  ON b.ColA = c.ColA
) AS temp 
ON a.ColA = temp.ColA
```

Which is not logically same as your second query. That's why, you are getting different result.

If you used `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you would get same result for both queries.

**N.B:** the above query will give you error because `tbl2` and `tbl3` both have a column with same name. so you may need to alias that to execute the above query properly.

Answer (score -2):

Please note that the database is free to decide in which order to process the tables. So especially oracle will change the query to its liking upon its internal statistics. Ofcourse only in a way that leads logically to the same results.

Putting the on clause directly to the tables to be joined makes it more readle.

So my recommendation is to do 
tb1 left out join tbl23 on tb1.xxx=tb2.yyy